# How can I interact with this span class? This is for an auto fill chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to have my chrome extension automatically select a drop down option. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but for my first step, I tackle the following html (top html is before selected state, second html line is after the selection is made):

html:

```
<md-select ng-disabled="!editIAreas || applicationReview.readOnly" ng-model="ia.iRecommendation" name="iRecommendation" aria-label="iRecommendation" 
<md-select ng-disabled="!editIAreas || applicationReview.readOnly" ng-model="ia.iRecommendation" name="iRecommendation" aria-label="iRecommendation: No"
```

javascript plugin to change the first attribute:

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="iRecommendation"]').setAttribute('aria-label', 'iRecommendation: No');
```

next attribute change:

```
class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty" 
class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse"
```

changed with:

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="iRecommendation"]').setAttribute('class', 'ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse');
```

The last thing I need to change (I believe) is this:

```
<b></b></div></span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value></md-select>
<b>Not Qualified</b></div></span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value></md-select>
```

How can I change the state of that? :O  Am I even doing this right?

edit: here's more of the last:

```
<span><div class="md-text"><b>Not Qualified</b></div></span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value></md-select>
```

edit2: so i need to set the text of md-text between `<b>  and </b>` how? I've been trying all day in console

Comment: Not sure if it is a help, but the `document.activeElement` is quite the help for me when trying to integrate with input elements at the HTML DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Comment: I'll try that now... i can't believe how much time I've spent on this silly dropdown box. insane. I may just have to post a new question because I'm attacking this from the wrong level, i think.